# Can a signet ring be a transport infrastructure part?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

I'm not sure about the following and thus my question if the ring would just be occult matrix part or transport infrastructure, or just a part of a transport infrastrucutre (especially what a demon would recognize it as).

I have a box which is a transport infrastructure. A containment device designed by the god machine. There is a signet ring which is designed to function as the only key to open this box and also to close and lock it again.

The box itself shows up as and is transport infrastructure so far is clear but what about the ring? What is it? and as what would it show up for a demon?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes/No** - This Signet Ring would be a piece of Concealment Infrastructure, not Transport or Logistics.

According to [Infrastructure](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Infrastructure),

> Infrastructures are the physical means, an arrangement of materials and manpower, by which the God-Machine manipulates the laws of physics to form an occult matrix that generates the desired Output.

As the ring is a physical part of this arrangement, it definitely qualifies as infrastructure.

While Transport Infrastructure is included under the Logistics heading:

> Logistics, means to locate, collect, and transport the equipment necessary for generating Output. Depending on the operation, these Infrastructures can vary a great deal, from ordinary metal gears to an ancient relic of a forgotten civilization.

A Signet Ring who's primary purpose is to prevent access to other pieces of Infrastructure
will fall under the Concealment heading:

> Concealment, means to hide its operation from outsiders. Some Concealment Infrastructures are mundane, like a fake restaurant to keep mortals from exploring the basement, others are supernatural, which likely explains why so few beings have a clue of the existence of the Machine

Much in the way a fake restaurant will keep mortals away from the basement, this Ring will keep mortals away from the interior of the box.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.
A key question is **would a duplicate of this ring function to open the box?**
If any duplicate would function (even if it had to be molecule position exact) to open the box then the ring is not part of the infrastructure, 
it is simply a property of the infrastructure that it will open if a physical object of this description is applied to it.

If on the other hand it has to be *this* ring, then it is part of the infrastructure.

If it is thus **not** part of the infrastructure, then it would not show up to demons at all -- though if you wanted to make it obvious  you could have it trigger Aetheric Resonance saying that a bit of Aether was stuck to the surface from the last time it had contact with the box.

If it **is** part of the infrastructure, then it would show up as infrastructure (which IIRC demons immediately know about). I would tell any demons detecting it as infrastructure that it is a component of the infrastructure, so they don't try and use the ring on its own.

You could break the infrastructure into two, one logistics and the other concealment as @Nyoze suggests. However I wouldn't, this kind of split definitely makes sense for bigger infrastructure (and I would encourage it), but for things so small it is a bit much work.

- Two pieces of infastructure means two linchpins. Means two vulnerabilities. Deciding what is a suitable linchpin for two things so small is hard.
- Second: You would have to have separate tasks for the logistic and concealment part, and if the box is just in the end a mundane box (not a portal to pocket realm or anything else) than that doesn't make sense.

If you hadn't already told the party that it was logistics infrastructure then saying the whole thing was concealment infrastructure would be valid. Though the line between concealment and logistics can be a bit blurred at times, so it doesn't matter really -- both are valid.

I would **not** try and think of it as a part of forming an occult matrix. Eg the notion that when the ring comes in contact with the box Output is produced in the form of the box which contains things. That kind of logic is much more prevalent in the mortal aimed God Machine Rules update than it is in the Demon rulebooks. I find it doesn't make too much sense except for infrastructure that is designed to be a big thing that happens as one-off, eg summoning an Angel, turning a meteor etc.

Comment: Hmmm could the ring also be the linchpin itself despite being part of the infrastructure?

Comment: Linchpins are always part of the infastructure. But in all the examples they are not parts that obviously do anything. One of the examples given in the book is a underground facity, below 3 brick obalisks. One is filled with wires and power conduits, one has a ventalation duct, and the third is solid brick. The third is the linchpin. So keeping with that theme, the linch pin for the box could be a price  sticker attached to the back, or a decorative filigree box corner. Or perhaps the band of the ring (assuming the face is what actually connects)

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, it's transport infrastructure.

It sounds like this signet ring is akin to a key to a fence-gate or switchstand -- it is *positive* access control to the piece of fixed infrastructure in question.  I would see it as transport infrastructure as well as a result, although it's not quite as clear-cut as the other possible case -- namely, that the signet ring is an *authority token*, as would be used in railway token block instrument.  In that case, the ring would be possessed by whoever's *using* the infrastructure at the time, as opposed to *granting access* to said piece of infrastructure.